# Can a docker image use executable from the host?

Tags: java, docker

I have several Java services, each packaged as a separate jar file. I plan to package the as docker images. Do I need to bundle the Java runtime on each image, or can I rely on the fact the host (that will run the image) already has the Java runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a volume to mount the Java runtime from the host into the container, but this makes the container less portable (as Andrew Fox points out).

If instead you use a common base image such as `java:8-jre` for your containers, the image will be shared between containers meaning that there is only one copy on disk (not one copy per container).

Not that in both cases, you will still have multiple JVMs running, one for each container.

Comment: Can you share something to support that? Is this behavior Java specific? Thanks!

Comment: Just look up how the CoW file system works. I reworded my answer to be a bit clearer what I mean. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/

Comment: It was wery good reading, thanks! In short, it is not Java specific, one can achieve the same easily... CoW stands for "copy on write".

Answer (score 2):

The idea of docker is to make your setup portable so if you don't put in the Java runtime you can't guarantee it will work properly on a destination system. I don't believe docker can access host executables unless there is a special whitelist setting somewhere but in my experience no it can't.

Comment: It depends, dependency, that there is JVM in some version is similar requirement as your image will run on same host OS or same Docker version... Just my point of view, no offense...